# How to append plain text row to a Google Spreadsheet with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code is supposed to append a new row to a Google Spreadsheet, but it doesn't.

```
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y9Vwfkg......');
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName('sheet_name');
sheet.appendRow("plain text to append");
```

I need help to append plain text (not an array) to a new row at the end of a specified sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option which is usually quicker when dealing with a lot of data is to use `getRange() and setValue()` instead.

For this, you will have to find the last row using `getLastRow()`.

```
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y9Vwfkg......');
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName('sheet_name');
var r_size = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(r_size+1,1).setValue("plain text to append");
```

> **References:**

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Answer (score 3):

[`sheet.appendRow(rowContents)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) requires that row contents be an array.  You can just wrap your text inside an array literal (`[]`).

```js
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y9Vwfkg......');
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName('sheet_name');
sheet.appendRow(["plain text to append"]); // <-- note added `[` and `]`
```